# How to repent for sins on "festive" days?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chagim-holidays, viduy-confession, nissan

On certain days of the year, viduy may not be recited (month of nissan, hol hamoed, rosh hodesh, etc.). If one did make a sin on one of these days, how can he/she repent for the sin on that same day?

Comment: _Viduy_ as in _Tachanun_ or _Nefilat Apayim_, I assume. (Some communities only say Viduy during Selichot.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, other communities say viduy every non-festive day of the year.

Comment: "how can he/she repent for the sin on that same day?" Why do you think there is a way to do that?

Comment: Do you have any reason/source to assume that a personal viduy essential to *teshuva* could be forbidden on *any* day?

Comment: @LN6595 Conceptually, we say that someone who sees a tzaddik perform an aveirah shouldn't be meharher acharav, since he surely did teshuvah that day. The gemara does NOT OBJECT to this on the bounds that it was a day where vidui is prohibited. Ergo, the prohibition of vidui does not pose an impediment to the process of teshuvah on these days, either because one may recite it privately, or because external recitation is not required for the process of teshuvah, or because something about these days obviates the need for vidui.

Comment: Charata Al Haavar Vikabala al Haasid -regret for the past and resolution for the future - rambam hilchos teshuva 2:2 -say Vidui at earliest possble time?

Comment: @SamuelManuel I thought I responded to this point but... who said that the Rambam's method of teshuvah must only be done with a tzibbur in shul? I would argue exactly the opposite - that a person can and should do teshuvah on his own, but we institute a "congregational" process to aid this.

Comment: Excellent comments everyone... How about some answers?

Answer (score -1):

The is a chassidic saying, "joy breaks all boundaries". Through the simcha of the yomim toivim one is able to reach a high level of teshuvah

Comment: What about saying Vidui? Isn't that a Mitzva Deorayta? http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1500.htm